# How can I make child process to not to execute parent code in python with `os.fork()`

Tags: python, multithreading, fork

I want to have a child process not execute remaining parent code after its forked.

I am achieving this by explicitly exiting the child process by checking process id returned by the `os.fork()` as in example below:

```
def fork_and_exit(fork_target):
    print("Inside fork_and_exit()")
    new_fork_id = os.fork()    
    if(new_fork_id == 0):
        fork_target()
        sys.exit(0)   #this prevent child from executing code below
                      #after returning from fork_target()

    print("Exiting fork_and_exit()")
    sys.exit(0)

def dummy_fork_target():
    print("Dummy fork target!!!")

fork_and_exit(dummy_fork_target)
```

The output of above is as follows:

```
Inside fork_and_exit()
Exiting fork_and_exit()
Dummy fork target!!!
```

The question is if above `fork_and_exit()` construct correct? I mean is it the right way to do and does people do it in this way only, or I am unnecessarily reinventing the wheel and there is some other well know / preferred approach to achieve this, which I am missing.

Comment: It is correct. All daemon and multiprocessing libraries I have seen do it the same way. Since it is a rather low-level use-case, I doubt a high-level wrapper or idiom is available or useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not inquire about solving a problem. The question seems more suitable to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) than StackOverflow.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's quite a specific question though. SO *should* be able to handle specific questions just fine.